# Functor from the category of varieties to the category of schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, affine-varieties

On the page : $ 58 $ of the following pdf: http://rgug.ch/medias/math/geometrie_algebrique.pdf , we find the proof of the theorem which says that there exists a fully faithful functor $ t $ from the category of varieties over $ K $ to the category of $ \mathrm{Spec} K $ - schemes : $ t: \mathrm{V}^K \to \mathcal{S} \mathrm{ch} (K) $.

The author of this proof tells us how to built this functor $t$, but the most important thing which is to show that $ t $ is fully faithful, which means that : $ \Phi: \mathrm {Hom}_{\mathbb{V}^{K}} (V, W) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{S} \mathrm{ch}} (t (V), t ( W)) $ is a natural bijection is not made in this pdf, look at the page: $ 60 $ to understand.

Hence, my question is :

In which book can i find a rest of this proof which says that: $ \Phi: \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{V}^{K}} (V, W ) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{S} \mathrm{ch}} (t (V), t (W)) $ is a natural bijection ( e.g : Injectivity + Surjectivity) ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Since you emphasize "injectivity + surjectivity", it might be worth reminding you that every natural *isomorphism* is a natural bijection. Often, it's easier to find an inverse than try to show injectivity and surjectivity directly.

Comment: (and philosophically, "isomorphism" is what you want here anyways; it just happens that set-valued functors have the property that natural bijections turn out to be natural isomorphisms)

Comment: Thank you very much, but i prefer to show injectivity ans surjectivity of $ \Phi $ to familiarize myself with category language. Can you write me a detailed proof of the injectivity and the surjectivity please ? Thank you.  :-)

Comment: IIRC Hartshorne shows this...

Comment: @user347489 : The Hartshorne's book doesn't contain a proof of injectivity and surjectivity of $ \Phi $ ... It only present the method of construction of $ \Phi $.  :-)

Comment: Harris and Eisenbud, *The Geometry of Schemes*, Theorem I-40 is that $\mathrm{Spec}$ is adjoint to taking global sections, which is enough to show what you need. I recommend checking out their proof.